# React Native HealthKit getDailyStepCountSamples returning undefined or empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, healthkit

I'm using react-native-health to create an app to read daily step counts. I have manually added steps on the simulator Health app and the data source is showing my app and all the Health permissions are on but when I try to getDailyStepCountSamples, I get an empty array.

Also, another issue I have is that I need to initiate HealthKit each time before getting the empty array otherwise I get 'undefined'. Once I initiate HealthKit again, it will return 'undefined' AND log 'Steps: []'. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
import AppleHealthKit from 'react-native-health';

export function useHealthKit({
    init = false,
    steps = false,
}) {
    const PERMS = AppleHealthKit.Constants.Permissions;

    const initiate = () => {
        let permissions = {
            permissions: {
                read: [
                    PERMS.StepCount,
                ],
            },
        };
        AppleHealthKit.initHealthKit(permissions, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Initialized!', results),
            }
        });
    };

    const getSteps = () => {
        let stepOptions = {
            startDate: new Date(2021, 1, 1).toISOString(),
        };
        AppleHealthKit.getDailyStepCountSamples(
            stepOptions,
            (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Steps: ', results);
            },
        );
    };
    init && initiate();
    steps && getSteps();
}
```

I call this by doing the following:

```
const SomeView = () => {
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => useHealthKit({init: true})>
        <Text>Initiate HealthKit</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button onPress={() => console.log(useHealthKit({steps: true}))>
        <Text>Console.log steps</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to do something very similar all afternoon and getting the same result as you.

What fixed it for me was using this bizarre trick from one of the [github threads](https://github.com/terrillo/rn-apple-healthkit/issues/38)

Basically you need to change your start date to **one month earlier than you want to sample** so in your case this would be 01/12/2020.

The original poster says this is caused by an issue in the C code.

I also set variables for `includeManuallyAdded: true` and `period: 1444` in my options variable

Worked for me, hopefully it will for you!